# LinkedIn Automation Script: Is There a Rate Limit for Removing Connections?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, linkedin-api, rate-limiting

I have developed an automated `Python` script for removing connections from `LinkedIn`. **However, I'm uncertain whether** `LinkedIn` **imposes any rate limits for removing connections on a daily or hourly basis**. I've researched on the internet but have not been able to find any information regarding if such **rate limits** exists. I did come across information about **a cap on the maximum number of connections that can be added weekly**, but this doesn't address my specific concern about connection removal.

***`The Python script that I'm using uses Selenium automation to simulate human interaction`***

My goal is to remove a total of **15,000 connections** from the `LinkedIn` account that I'm working with. Currently, I've been testing the script with a maximum of **75 connections** removed per day and with no `rate limits` problems so far. But I want to be able to scale **to the maximum number possible**.

That's why I really need to know if there are `rate limits` for removing connections from `LinkedIn` in bulk because **I don't want to flag the account that I'm using it**.

***`PS: I'M NOT USING THE LINKEDIN API BUT THAT'S THE ONLY TAG RELATED TO LINKEDIN AVAILABLE`***

Comment: Since this question is related to the server-side of `LinkedIn`, that's why I didn't think it was necessary to post the `Python` script that I'm using.

Comment: Why would LinkedIn reveal this info to public if you are not using the LinkedIn apis; and that is why for these kind of exclusive functionality they provide their APIs; You should read the linkedin developer apis documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[Documents Rate Limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/rate-limits)

Go through this documentation atleast you will get some answers , and the exact numbers no firm will disclose